# Delete table thead in css

Tags: html, css

I use `Markdown/pagedown extra` in javascript that produces a table using:

```
col1|col2
---|---
xxx|xxx
xxx|xxx
xxx|xxx

Markdown.Extra.init(converter, {table_class: "mytable"});
```

this generates html:

```
<table class='mytable'>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>col1</th>
  <th>col2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr>
  <td>xxx</td>
  <td>xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>xxx</td>
  <td>xxx</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>xxx</td>
  <td>xxx</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

I want to hide/delete the `thead` and only show the rows.
When using:

```
.mytable thead th {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

it looks like:

[image]

Using jquery I can remove the `thead` for all tables on a certain page:

```
for (i=0; i < $('table').length; i++) { 
  $('table')[i].deleteTHead(); 
}
```

But I see a slight flicker and see the header being deleted.

[image]

Question:
Is there another way? Can this be done using CSS to remove/hide the header completely?

Comment: CSS basics: `visibility:hidden` reserves the space an element would have taken was it visible, whereas `display:none` removes it totally from display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not do something like:

```
thead, th {display: none;}
```

The reason being, `visibility: hidden;` will still show the space occupied by the element.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS's simplest form, `display:none`

```
th{
display:none;
}
```